# TSQL return distinct rows based on the preferred value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I run the following SQL against a SQL Server database:

```
SELECT 
    t1.id, t1.name, t2.status
FROM 
    t1 
JOIN 
    t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE 
    t1.id = t2.id
```

I get the following results

```
id   name   status
------------------- 
1    bob    active
1    bob    draft
2    jim    active
3    ted    draft
```

I'm trying to figure out how to construct the `WHERE` statement to get the following desired result.

```
id   name   status 
-------------------
1    bob    active
2    jim    active
3    ted    draft
```

Basically the problem I'm trying to solve is removing duplicate rows when there are multiple status and removing the row in favor of the status active, I'm really trying to avoid nested queries or intersects if possible.

Comment: What is the preferred status? Could you provide the sample data for `t1` and `t2`.

Comment: your join condition is `t1.id = t2.id`. Do both tables have the same id field? or you meant something like `t1.statusid = t2.id`

Comment: The preferred status is `Active` if both `Active` and `Draft` exist.

Comment: @ughai assume for the sake of the example that t1.id is the PK for t1 and t2.id is a FK referencing t1.id.

Comment: @ImaginateWayne - My answer should help you in that case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` with `CASE` like this

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.status,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER BY CASE WHEN t2.status = 'active' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC) rn
FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: You could remove `WHERE t1.id = t2.id` as this also happens to be the `JOIN` condition.

Comment: @wewesthemenace - true. Even the `JOIN` condition looks a little weird  `t1.id = t2.id`

Comment: Thanks @ughai this worked a treat and was my first step into a bigger world beyond basic CRUD operations. 
I can now add CTE and ROW_NUMBER() to my TSQL tool-belt!